# How can i post data from view to controller in laravel 5.0?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in laravel, i'm trying to pass data from view to controller but getting some errors. I have searched but didn't got how can i solve this issue. Please view my code and advice me where i'm wrong?

### demoview.blade.php Code

```
echo Form::open(array( 'method' => 'post','action' => 'DemoController@savess'));
echo Form::label('name', 'Name');
echo Form::text('name');
echo Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address');
echo Form::text('email');
echo  Form::close();
```

### DemoController.php Code

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DemoController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Welcome Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller renders the "marketing page" for the application and
    | is configured to only allow guests. Like most of the other sample
    | controllers, you are free to modify or remove it as you desire.
    |
    */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application welcome screen to the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function demofunction()
    {
        $users = \DB::table('user')->get();
        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
            echo  $user->name;
            echo  $user->email;
        }

        return view('demoview');
    }

    public function savess(){
    }
}
```

### Routes.php Code

```
Route::get('demo', 'DemoController@demofunction');
```

### Error :

```
ErrorException in compiled.php line 8658:
Action App\Http\Controllers\DemoController@savess not defined. (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\ayaz\resources\views\demoview.blade.php)




InvalidArgumentException in compiled.php line 8658:
Action App\Http\Controllers\DemoController@savess not defined.
```

Comment: So when the user submits the form you want to capture the `POST` data in the `savess()` function?

Comment: @James yes exactly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to `routes.php` this line:

```
Route::post("savess", "DemoController@savess");
```